# Error while using if else in where clause

Tags: sql-server

I am passing two variables like `SDate` and `EDate` to stored procedure and I want select data from table where `VDAte` is betwwen `SDate` and `EDate` if both `SDate` and `EDate` is not null .If `EDate` is null then I want to select data where  `VDAte` = `SDAte`.I have tried using `If..Else` and `Case` in where clause but it was giving incorrect syntx error.
Query :

```
SELECT 
    Column1 
    ,column2
from Table t
where t.VDate IN
    (
    If EDate IS NOT NULL
     SELECT 
        VDate 
    FROM Table 
    where VDate BETWEEN SDate AND EDate
    ELSE
     SDate
    )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have some typos in your query, at least the `select` keyword is wrong and I guess you referenced `column2` in your projection instead aliasing `column` as `2`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tweaking the names a bit,

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
 from MyTable
 where VDate between @SDate and isnull(@EDate, @SDate)
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the following query:

```
SELECT
    Column1,
    Column2

FROM
    Table t

WHERE
    t.VDate IN (
        SELECT
            VDate

        FROM
            Table

        WHERE
            VDate BETWEEN SDate AND EDate
        AND
            EDate is not null
    )
OR
    (
        t.VDate = SDate
    AND
        EDate is null
    )
```

If `EDate` is not null `t.VDate` is between `SDate` and `EDate`, otherwise `t.VDate = SDate`.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you can't use IF in where clause this way.

So, if the data you compare depends on EDate value, you could do this way:

```
SELECT Column1 ,column2
from Table t
WHERE
    (t.EDate IS NOT NULL AND t.VDate IN (SELECT VDate FROM Table where VDate BETWEEN SDate AND EDate))
    OR (t.EDate IS NULL AND t.VDate IN (SELECT SDate FROM Table))
```

If EDate is not null, query selects the VDates with between. And if is null, the other one.

Comment: Please consider elaborating on your answer.

Comment: Can you please explain this code (in your answer)? You may get more upvotes that way!

Comment: tryed to explain a little more

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
 from MyTable
 where (VDate between @SDate and @EDate and (@SDate+@EDate is not null)) or (VDate = @Sdate and @Edate is null)
```

Also @Philip Kelley answer is a good approach